# Cómo hago que el promedio no salga dos veces?

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer unu programa para registrar las n calificaciones de m alumnos, calcular y desplegar su promedio.
También desplegar si esta aprobado con calificación mayor o igual a 70, en caso contrario no aprobado.
Al final debe indicar la cantidad de aprobados y la cantidad de no aprobados.

El programa está pero tengo un problema, a la hora de mostrar el promedio, me arroja el promedio del ultimo en todos los demás y no sé porqué, alguien podría darme algun consejo o decirme que estoy escribiendo mal?

````
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int CantidadAlumnos,   ControlAlumnos;
  int CantidadAprovados=0, CantidadReprovados=0;
  int CantidadCalificaciones,  ControlCalificaciones;
  int Suma, Promedio;
  int CantidadAprobados = 0, CantidadNoAprobados = 0;

  cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos para capturar calificaciones: ";
  cin >> CantidadAlumnos;
  cout << "Cantidad de calificaciones por alumno: ";
  cin >> CantidadCalificaciones;
  cin.ignore();
  
  string alumno[CantidadAlumnos];
  int Calificaciones[CantidadCalificaciones];
  
  // Captura de Alumnos y Calificaciones
  for (ControlAlumnos=0; ControlAlumnos < CantidadAlumnos; ControlAlumnos++){
      cout << "Nombre del Alumno " << ControlAlumnos + 1 << ": ";
      getline(cin,alumno[ControlAlumnos]);
      for (ControlCalificaciones = 0; ControlCalificaciones < CantidadCalificaciones; ControlCalificaciones++){
          cout << "Calificacion " << ControlCalificaciones + 1 << ": ";
          cin >> Calificaciones[ControlCalificaciones];
          cin.ignore();
      }

  }
  
  // Calculo del Promedio
  for (ControlAlumnos=0; ControlAlumnos < CantidadAlumnos; ControlAlumnos++){
      Suma = 0;
      
      cout << "Promedio del Alumno: " << alumno[ControlAlumnos] << ": ";
  
      
      for (ControlCalificaciones = 0; ControlCalificaciones < CantidadCalificaciones; ControlCalificaciones++){
          
          Promedio=0;
          //Suma += Calificaciones[ControlCalificaciones];
          
          
          Suma = Suma + Calificaciones[ControlCalificaciones];
      
      }
          
          Promedio = Suma / CantidadCalificaciones;
          cout << Promedio << endl;
              
      
      if (Promedio>=70)
      {
      cout<<"aprobado"<<endl;
      cout<<endl;
      CantidadAprovados=CantidadAprovados+1;
      }
      else
      {
      cout<<"no aprobado"<<endl;
      cout<<endl;
      CantidadReprovados=CantidadReprovados+1;
      }
      
  }
  // Calcular cantidad de Aprobados y Reprobados
  cout<<"la cantidad de reprobados es: "<<CantidadReprovados<<endl;
  cout<<"la cantidad de aprobados es: "<<CantidadAprovados<<endl;
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, el problema que tienes es que solo tienes un lugar dónde guardar las calificaciones de un solo estudiante, podemos verlo en cómo defines la variable en dónde se guardan las calificaciones:

```
int Calificaciones[CantidadCalificaciones];
```

Como puedes ver solo tienes espacio para guardar las calificaciones de un estudiante y cuando pides las calificaciones para un estudiante lo que estás haciendo es simplemente reescribiendo sobre esta variable.

Te recomiendo usar un array de dos dimensiones para poder guardar en él las calificaciones de cada estudiante, la declaración de la variable sería algo así:

```
int Calificaciones[CantidadAlumnos][CantidadCalificaciones];
```

Y el resto de la implementación solo cambiaría en el sentido de que accedes el estudiante antes de acceder al array de calificaciones que habita dentro de este array de dos dimensiones, se vería así:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_CANTIDAD_DE_ALUMNOS 50
#define MAX_CANTIDAD_DE_NOTAS   10


int main ()
{

  int CantidadAlumnos, ControlAlumnos;
  int CantidadAprovados = 0, CantidadReprovados = 0;
  int CantidadCalificaciones, ControlCalificaciones;
  int Suma, Promedio;
  int CantidadAprobados = 0, CantidadNoAprobados = 0;

  cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos para capturar calificaciones: ";
  cin >> CantidadAlumnos;
  cout << "Cantidad de calificaciones por alumno: ";
  cin >> CantidadCalificaciones;
  cin.ignore ();

  string alumno[MAX_CANTIDAD_DE_ALUMNOS];
  int Calificaciones[MAX_CANTIDAD_DE_ALUMNOS][MAX_CANTIDAD_DE_NOTAS];

  // Captura de Alumnos y Calificaciones
  for (ControlAlumnos = 0; ControlAlumnos < CantidadAlumnos; ControlAlumnos++)
    {
      cout << "Nombre del Alumno " << ControlAlumnos + 1 << ": ";
      getline (cin, alumno[ControlAlumnos]);
      for (ControlCalificaciones = 0;
       ControlCalificaciones < CantidadCalificaciones;
       ControlCalificaciones++)
    {
      cout << "Calificacion " << ControlCalificaciones + 1 << ": ";
      cin >> Calificaciones[ControlAlumnos][ControlCalificaciones];
      cin.ignore ();
    }

    }

  // Calculo del Promedio
  for (ControlAlumnos = 0; ControlAlumnos < CantidadAlumnos; ControlAlumnos++)
    {
      Suma = 0;

      cout << "Promedio del Alumno: " << alumno[ControlAlumnos] << ": ";

      for (ControlCalificaciones = 0;
       ControlCalificaciones < CantidadCalificaciones;
       ControlCalificaciones++)
    {

      Promedio = 0;
      //Suma += Calificaciones[ControlCalificaciones];


      Suma = Suma + Calificaciones[ControlAlumnos][ControlCalificaciones];

    }

      Promedio = Suma / CantidadCalificaciones;
      cout << Promedio << endl;


      if (Promedio >= 70)
    {
      cout << "aprobado" << endl;
      cout << endl;
      CantidadAprovados = CantidadAprovados + 1;
    }
      else
    {
      cout << "no aprobado" << endl;
      cout << endl;
      CantidadReprovados = CantidadReprovados + 1;
    }

    }
  // Calcular cantidad de Aprobados y Reprobados
  cout << "la cantidad de reprobados es: " << CantidadReprovados << endl;
  cout << "la cantidad de aprobados es: " << CantidadAprovados << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Por cierto te felicito, si bien puedes mejorar en como se hace la implementación (lo cuál es entendible porque supongo que estás aprendiendo) y la manera en la que formulas la pregunta (como dice @gbianchi en el comentario), este es un código muy ordenado, me fue muy fácil entender qué estabas haciendo y se me facilitó implementar el array bidimensional por cómo lo escribiste.

UPDATE:

Cómo dice [@user3733164](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15856/user3733164) es una mala práctica crear un array estático a partir de una variable que no es constante, como en:

```
int Calificaciones[CantidadAlumnos][CantidadCalificaciones];
```

Algunas soluciones que se me ocurren es asignar la memoria de manera dinámica o parametrizar el tamaño máximo de tu array por medio de una variable global constante o un `#define`. Edite mi solución con la segunda opción porque es más sencilla de implementar, cabe destacar que si quisieras seguir este camino tendrías que validar que el usuario no ingrese una cantidad de alumnos o una cantidad de calificaciones mayor a la definida en tus parámetros.

Comment: Sería bueno recordarle que no es buena práctica usar arrays de tamaño variable. Si tiene que implementar arrays en tiempo de ejecución, debería usar memoria dinámica o algún tipo de contenedor.

Comment: @user3733164 no hay que recordar que no es buena práctica, hay que **insistir** en que no es una práctica recomendable ni adecuada de ninguna de las maneras.

Comment: Tras tantos años me corto mucho en este sitio :-)

Comment: @user3733164 Tienes toda la razón, gracias por la sugerencia, te mencioné en la respuesta.